# Explain query mysql when have where in main table change

Tags: join, select, left-join, explain, where-in

I have query like that

```
            SELECT stock.chassi_no, '가상계좌' AS title, 'vacs' AS type, concat(tr_no,'|vac') AS id, tr_il as date, tr_si as time, tr_amt as price, iacct_nm as account_name, iacct_no as account_no, sale.staff_cn as staff_user_cn, sale.staff_no as staff_user_no, sale.is_car_assigned, sale.contract_no,
               IF(ISNULL(auth_group.name), tb_retirees.rt_part_name, auth_group.name) as staff_dept, 
               auth_group.eng_name AS staff_dept_en, auth_group.eng_short as staff_dep_es, auth_group.country as staff_dept_country,
               c.name as customer_name, model.name as car_model, if(sale.state = 'success', 1, 0) as state
        FROM vacs_ahst 
        LEFT JOIN crm_bps_ncsm_sales AS sale ON vacs_ahst.iacct_no = sale.virtual_acc_no
        LEFT JOIN crm_bps_ncsm_stock AS stock ON sale.stock_cn = stock.cn AND sale.stock_id = stock.id
        LEFT JOIN crm_product_group as model ON model.cn = stock.pg_cn AND model.group_id = stock.pg_id AND model.is_del = 0
        LEFT JOIN crm_bps_ncsm_sales_customers as s_c ON s_c.sales_id = sale.sales_id AND s_c.customer_no = (SELECT customer_no FROM crm_bps_ncsm_sales_customers WHERE sales_cn = sale.cn AND sales_id = sale.sales_id ORDER BY rate DESC limit 1)
        LEFT JOIN crm_customer_base as c ON c.cn = s_c.customer_cn AND c.id = s_c.customer_no
        LEFT JOIN auth_user_group ON auth_user_group.cn = sale.staff_cn AND auth_user_group.user_no = sale.staff_no AND auth_user_group.is_default_group = 1
        LEFT JOIN auth_group ON auth_group.group_id = auth_user_group.group_id AND auth_group.cn = auth_user_group.cn
        LEFT JOIN tb_retirees ON tb_retirees.cn = sale.staff_cn AND tb_retirees.rt_uno =  sale.staff_no
        WHERE vacs_ahst.inp_st = '1'    
                    ORDER BY date DESC  LIMIT 0, 10
```

when Explain table vacs_ahst will be main

[image]

but i add where in like that

```
        SELECT stock.chassi_no, '가상계좌' AS title, 'vacs' AS type, concat(tr_no,'|vac') AS id, tr_il as date, tr_si as time, tr_amt as price, iacct_nm as account_name, iacct_no as account_no, sale.staff_cn as staff_user_cn, sale.staff_no as staff_user_no, sale.is_car_assigned, sale.contract_no,
               IF(ISNULL(auth_group.name), tb_retirees.rt_part_name, auth_group.name) as staff_dept, 
               auth_group.eng_name AS staff_dept_en, auth_group.eng_short as staff_dep_es, auth_group.country as staff_dept_country,
               c.name as customer_name, model.name as car_model, if(sale.state = 'success', 1, 0) as state
        FROM vacs_ahst 
        LEFT JOIN crm_bps_ncsm_sales AS sale ON vacs_ahst.iacct_no = sale.virtual_acc_no
        LEFT JOIN crm_bps_ncsm_stock AS stock ON sale.stock_cn = stock.cn AND sale.stock_id = stock.id
        LEFT JOIN crm_product_group as model ON model.cn = stock.pg_cn AND model.group_id = stock.pg_id AND model.is_del = 0
        LEFT JOIN crm_bps_ncsm_sales_customers as s_c ON s_c.sales_id = sale.sales_id AND s_c.customer_no = (SELECT customer_no FROM crm_bps_ncsm_sales_customers WHERE sales_cn = sale.cn AND sales_id = sale.sales_id ORDER BY rate DESC limit 1)
        LEFT JOIN crm_customer_base as c ON c.cn = s_c.customer_cn AND c.id = s_c.customer_no
        LEFT JOIN auth_user_group ON auth_user_group.cn = sale.staff_cn AND auth_user_group.user_no = sale.staff_no AND auth_user_group.is_default_group = 1
        LEFT JOIN auth_group ON auth_group.group_id = auth_user_group.group_id AND auth_group.cn = auth_user_group.cn
        LEFT JOIN tb_retirees ON tb_retirees.cn = sale.staff_cn AND tb_retirees.rt_uno =  sale.staff_no
        WHERE stock.pg_id IN (1614,1620,1623,1628,1631,1633,1639,1641,1650,1653,1656,1658,1661,1667,1674,1677,1681,1685,1688,1690,1694,1698,1700,1702,1705,1708,1711,1713,1715,1718,1722,1725,1728,1734,1738,1742,1744,1748,1753,1757,1760,1762,1766,1771,1774,1778,1789,1794,1798,1802,1804,1807,1811,1814,1818,1821,1824,1826,1828,1831,1835,1838,1840,1843,1847,1852,1855,1858,1861,1969,1971,1974,1976,1983,1985,1990,1993,2000,2008,2010,2016,2019,2021,2024,2038,2046,2055,2060,2063,2071,2073,2075,2353,2359,2364,2367,2370,2372,2374,2377,2379,2381,2383,2385,2388,2393,2395,2399,2401,2403,2405,2407,2410,2412,2414,2416,2418,2420,2422,2424,2426,2428,2430,2432,2434,2437,2439,2441,2443,2446,2448,2450,2452,2454,2456,2458,2462,2466,2468,2470,2472,2474,2476,2478,2480,2482,2486,2488,2490,2496,2498,2504,2506,2508,2510,2512,2520,2524,2526,2528,2530,2534,2536,2538,2544,2548,2550,2552,2556,2560,2562,2566,2568,2572,3820,3821,3822,3823,3824,3825,3826,3827,3828,3829,3830,3831,3832,3833,3836,3837,3838,3839,3840,3843,3844,3845,3846,3848,3849,3850,3862,3863,3864,3865,3866,3867,3868,3869,3870,3872,3873,3874,3878,3881,3882,3883,3893,3895,3897,3900,3901,3902,3903,3904,3905,3906,3908,3910,3911,3914,3915,3916,3917,3918,3920,3921,3922,3924,3926,3927,3934,3936,3937,3938,3940,3941,3945,3946,3947,3950,3951,3952,3960,3963,3964,3967,3968,3970,3974,3975,3977,3984,3985,3988,3989,4026,4027,4028,4029,4030,4031,4032,4033,4034,4035,4036,4037,4038,4039,4040,4041,4042,4043,4044,4045,4046,4047,4048,4049,4051,4052,4053,4054,4055,4056,4057,4058,4059,4060,4061,4063,4064,4065,4066,4067,4068,4069,4070,4071,4072,4073,4074,4075,4077,4078,4080,4081,4083,4084,4085,4086,4088,4089,4091,4092,4093,4094,4095,4110,4112,4113,4114,4115,4116,4117,4118,4119,4120,4121,4122,4123,4124,4125,4127,4129,4130,4131,4132,4133,4134,4135,4136,4137,4138,4139,4144,4146,4148,4150,4152,4153,4154,4156,4157,4158,4161,4241,4242,4243,4244,4245,4246,4248,4249,4250,4251,4252,4253,4254,4255,4256,4258,4259,4260,4261,4262,4263,4264,4265,4269,4270,4285,4286,4287,4288,4289,4290,4291,4292,4293,4294,4295,4296,4297,4298,4299,4300,4301,4302,4303,4304,4305,4307,4308,4309,4311,4312,4313,4315,4316,4317,4318,4319,4322,4325,4326,4330,4332,4334,4340,4341,4344,4345,4349,4356,4357,4358,4359,4360,4361,4362,4363,4364,4365,4366,4367,4368,4369,4370,4372,4374,4376,4377,4379,4380,4381,4382,4383,4384,4388,4390,4391,4392,4393,4394,4396,4397,4398,4399,4400,4401,4402,4403,4406,4407,4409,4411,4412,4413,4414,4416,4418,4419,4420,4421,4422,4424,4425,4426,4427,4428,4429,4431,4432,4433,4434,4435,4436,4437,4438,4439,4440,4441,4442,4444,4445,4446,4449,4451,4453,4456,4457,4461,4463,4464,4465,4467,4468,4469,4470,4471,4472,4473,4474,4475,4476,4477,4478,4479,4480,4481,4482,4483,4484,4485,4486,4487,4488,4489,4490,4491,4494,4495,4496,4497,4498,4500,4501,4502,4503,4504,4505,4506,4507,4508,4509,4513,4516,4517,4518,4519,4520,4523,4524,4527,4529,4530,4531,4532,4534,4538,4539,4540,4541,4542,4543,4544,4545,4546,4547,4548,4549,4550,4551,4552,4555,4556,4557,4558,4559,4560,4561,4562,4563,4564,4565,4566,4567,4568,4569,4570,4571,4572,4573,4574,4575,4576,4577,4578,4579,4580,4581,4582,4584,4585,4586,4587,4590,4595,4596,4597,4598,4599,4600,4601,4602,4603,4604,4605,4606,4607,4608,4609,4610,4611,4612,4613,4616,4617,4618,4619,4620,4621,4622,4623,4624,4625,4626,4627,4628,4629,4630,4631,4632,4633,4634,4635,4636,4637,4638,4639,4643,4644,4645,4646,4647,4648,4649,4650,4651,4652,4653,4654,4655,4656,4657,4658,4659,4660,4661,4662,4663,4664,4665,4666,4667,4668,4670,4671,4672,4673,4674,4675,4679,4680,4681,4682,4683,4684,4685,4689,4690,4691,4693,4694,4695,4696,4697,4698,4699,4700,4701,4702,4709,4710,4711,4712,4713,4715,4716,4717,4718,4719,4720,4721,4722,4723,4724,4725,4726,4727,4728,4729,4730,4731,4732,4733,4734,4735,4736,4737,4738,4740,4741,4742,4743,4744,4745,4746,4747,4753,4754,4759,4760,4761,4762,4763,4764,4766,4767,4768,4769,4770,4776,4777,4778,4779,4780,4781,4782,4783,4784,4785,4786,4787,4788,4789,4790,4791,4792,4793,4794,4795,4796,4797,4798,4799,4800,4801,4802,4803,4804,4805,4806,4807,4808,4809,4810,4811,4812,4813,4814,4815,4816,4817,4818,4819,4820,4821,4822,4823,4824,4825,4828,4829,4830,4831,4832,4833,4834,4835,4836,4837,4838,4840,4841,4845,4846,4847,4848,4849,4850,4851,4852,4853,4854,4855,4856,4857,4858,4859,4860,4861,4862,4863,4864,4865,4866,4867,4868,4869,4870,4871,4872,4873,4874,4875,4876,4877,4878,4879,4880,4881,4882,4883,4884,4885,4886,4887,4888,4889,4890,4891,4892,4893,4894,4895,4896,4897,4898,4899,4900,4901,4902,4903,4904,4911,4912,4913,4914,4915,4916,4917,4918,4919,4920,4921,4922,4923,4924,4926,4931,4932,4933,4934,4935,4936,4937,4938,4939,4940,4941,4942,4956,4957,4958,4959,4960,4961,4962,4963,4965,4966,4967,4968,4969,4979,4980,4991,4992,4993,4994,4995,4996,4997,4998,4999,5000,5001,5002,5003,5004,5005,5006,5007,5008,5009,5010,5011,5012,5013,5014,5015,5016,5017,5018,5019,5020,5021,5022,5023,5024,5025,5026,5027,5028,5029,5030,5031,5032,5033,5034,5035,5036,5037,5038,5039,5040,5041,5045,5049,5051,5052,5053,5054,5055,5057,5058,5059,5060,5061,5062,5063,5064,5065,5066,5067,5068,5069,5070,5077,5078,5080,5084,5085,5086,5087,5088,5089,5092,5093,5094,5095,5096,5097,5098,5099,5100,5101,5103,5104,5105,5106,5107,5108,5109,5112,5114,5115,5116,5117,5118,5119,5120,5121,5122,5123,5124,5125,5126,5127,5128,5129,5130,5131,5132,5133,5134,5135,5136,5137,5138,5139,5140,5141,5142,5143,5144,5145,5146,5147,5148,5149,5150,5151,5152,5153,5154,5155,5156,5157,5159,5160,5161,5162,5163,5164,5165,5166,5167,5168,5169,5170,5171,5172,5173,5174,5175,5176,5177,5178,5179,5180,5181,5182,5186,5187,5188,5189,5190,5191,5195,5196,5197,5198,5199,5200,5201,5202,5203,5204,5205,5206,5207,5208,5209,5210,5211,5212,5213,5214,5215,5216,5217,5218,5219,5222,5229,5230,5231,5232,5233,5234,5235,5236,5237,5238,5240,5241,5242,5243,5244,5245,5246,5247,5248,5249,5250,5251,5252,5253,5254,5255,5256,5257,5258,5259,5260,5261,5262,5263,5264,5265,5266,5267,5268,5269,5270,5271,5272,5273,5274,5275,5276,5277,5278,5279,5280,5281,5282,5283,5284,5285,5286,5287,5288,5289,5290,5291,5292,5293,5294,5295,5296,5297,5298,5299,5300,5301,5302,5303,5304,5305,5306,5307,5308,5309,5310,5311,5312,5313,5314,5315,5316,5319,5320,5321,5322,5323,5324,5326,5327,5328,5329,5330,5331,5332,5333,5334,5335,5336,5337,5338,5339,5340,5341,5342,5343,5344,5345,5346,5347,5348,5349,5350,5351,5352,5353,5354,5355,5356,5357,5358,5359,5360,5361,5362,5363,5364,5365,5366,5367,5368,5369,5370,5371,5372,5373,5374,5375,5376,5377,5378,5379,5380,5381,5382,5383,5384,5385,5386,5387,5388,5389,5390,5391,5392,5393,5394,5395,5396,5397,5398,5399,5400,5401,5402,5403,5404,5405,5406,5407,5408,5409,5410,5411,5412,5413,5414,5415,5416,5417,5418,5419,5420,5421,5422,5423,5424,5425,5426,5427,5428,5429,5430,5431,5432,5433,5434,5435,5436,5437,5438,5439,5440,5442,5443,5444,5445,5446,5447,5448,5449,5450,5451,5452,5453,5454,5455,5456,5457,5458,5459,5460,5461,5462,5463,5464,5465,5466,5471,5472,5473,5474,5475,5476,5477,5478,5480,5481,5482,5483,5484,5485,5489,5490,5491,5492,5493,5494,5495,5496,5497,5498,5499,5500,5501,5502,5503,5504,5505,5506,5507,5508,5509,5510,5511,5512,5513,5514,5515,5516,5517,5518,5519,5520,5521,5522,5523,5524,5525,5526,5527,5528,5529,5530,5531,5532,5533,5534,5535,5536,5537,5538,5539,5540,5545,5546,5547,5548,5549,5550,5551,5552,5553,5554,5555,5557,5558,5559,5560,5561,5562,5563,5564,5565,5566,5567,5568,5569,5570,5571,5572,5582,5583,5584,5585,5586,5588,5589,5590,5591,5592,5593,5594,5595,5596,5597,5598,5599,5600,5602,5603,5604,5605,5606,5607,5608,5609,5610,5611,5612,5613,5614,5615,5616,5617,5618,5619,5620,5621,5622,5623,5624,5625,5626,5627,5628,5629,5630,5631,5632,5633,5634,5635,5636,5637,5638,5639,5640,5641,5642,5643,5644,5646,5647,5648,5649,5650,5651,5652,5654,5655,5656,5657,5661,5662,5663,5664,5665,5666,5667,5668,5669,5670,5671,5672,5673,5674,5675,5676,5677,5678,5679,5680,5681,5682,5683,5684,5685,5686,5687,5688,5689,5690,5691,5692,5693,5694,5695,5696,5697,5698,5699,5700,5701,5702,5703,5704,5705,5706,5707,5708,5709,5710,5711,5712,5713,5714,5715,5716,5718,5719,5720,5721,5722,5723,5724,5725,5726,5727,5728,5729,5730,5731,5753,5762,5763,5764,5765,5766,5767,5768,5769,5770,5771,5772,5773,5774,12221,12222,12228,12229,12230,12231,12232,12233,12234,12235,13635,13636,13637,13638,13639,13640,13641,13642,13643,13644,13645,13646,13647,13648,13649,13650,13651,13652,13653,13654,13655,13656,13657,13658,13659,13660,13661,13662,13663,13664,13665,13666,13667,13668,13669,13671,38175,38176,38177,38178,38179,38180,38181,38182,38183,38184,38185,38186,38187,38188,38189,38190,38191,38192,38193,38194,38195,38196,38197,38198,38199,38200,38201,38202,38203,38204,38205,38206,38207,38208,38209,38212,38213,38214,38215,38216,38217,38218,38219,38220,38221,38222,38223,38224,38225,38226,38227,38228,38229,38230,38231,38232,38233,38234,38235,38236,38237,38238,38239,38240,38241,38242,38243,38244,38245,38246,38247,38248,38249,38250,38251,38252,38253,38254,38255,38256,38257,38258,38259,38260,38261,38263,38264,38265,38266,38267,38268,38269,38270,38271,38272,38273,38274,38275,38276,38277,38278,38279,38280,38281,38282,38283,38284,38285,38286,38287,38288,38289,38290,38291,38292,38293,38294,38295,38296,38297,38298,38299,38300,38301,38302,38303,38304,38305,38306,38307,38308,38309,38310,38311,38312,38313,38314,38315,38316,38317,38318,38319,38320,38321,38322,38324,38325,38326,38327,38328,38329,38330,38331,38332,38333,38334,38335,38336,38337,38338,38339,38340,38341,38342,38343,38344,38345,38346,38347,38348,38349,38350,38351,38352,38353,38354,38355,38356,38357,38358,38359,38360,38361,38362,38363,38364,38365,38366,38367,38368,38369,38370,38371,38372,38373,38374,38375,38376,38377,38378,38379,38380,38381,38382,38383,38384,38385,38386,38387,38388,38389,38390,38391,38392,38393,38394,38395,38396,38397,38398,38399,38400,38401,38402,38403,38404,38405,38406,38407,38408,38409,38410,38411,38412,38413,38414,38415,38416,38417,38418,38419,38420,38421,38422,38423,38424,38425,38426,38427,38428,38429,38430,38431,38432,38433,38434,38435,38436,38437,38438,38439,38440,38441,38442,38443,38444,38445,38446,38447,38448,38449,38450,38451,38452,38453,38454,38455,38456,38457,38458,38459,38460,38461,38462,38463,38464,38465,38466,38467,38468,38469,38470,38471,38472,38473,38474,38475,38476,38477,38478,38479,38480,38481,38482,38483,38484,38485,38486,38487,38488,38489,38490,38491,38492,38493,38494,38495,38496,38497,38498,38499,38500,38501,38502,38503,38504,38505,38506,38507,38508,38509,38510,38511,38512,38513,38514,38515,38516,38517,38518,38519,38520,38521,38522,38523,38524,38525,38526,38527,38528,38529,38530,38531,38532,38533,38534,38535,38536,38537,38538,38539,38540,38541,38542,38543,38544,38545,38546,38547,38548,38549,38550,38551,38552,38553,38554,38555,38556,38557,38558,38559,38560,38561,38562,38563,38564,38565,38566,38567,38568,38569,38570,38571,38572,38573,38574,38575,38576,38577,38578,38579,38580,38581,38582,38583,38584,38585,38586,38587,38588,38589,38590,38591,38592,38593,38594,38595,38596,38597,38598,38599,38600,38601,38602,38603,38604,38605,38606,38607,38608,38609,38610,38611,38612,38613,38614,38615,38616,38617,38618,38619,38620,38621,38622,38623,38624,38625,38626,38627,38628,38629,38630,38631,38632,38633,38634,38635,38636,38637,38638,38639,38640,38641,38642,38643,38644,38645,38646,38647,38648,38649,38650,38651,38652,38653,38654,38655,38657,38658,38659,38660,38661,38662,38663,38664,38665,38666,38667,38668,38669,38670,38671,38672,38673,38674,38675,38676,38677,38678,38679,38680,38681,38682,38683,38684,38685,38686,38687,38688,38689,38690,38691,38692,38693,38694,38695,38696,38697,38698,38699,38700,38701,38702,38703,38704,38705,38706,38707,38708,38709,38710,38711,38712,38713,38714,38715,38716,38717,38718,38719,38720,38721,38722,38723,38724,38725,38726,38727,38728,38729,38730,38731,38732,38733,38734,38735,38736,38737,38738,38739,38740,38741,38742,38743,38744,38745,38746,38747,38748,38749,38750,38751,38752,38753,38754,38755,38756,38757,38758,38759,38760,38761,38762,38763,38764,38765,38766,38767,38768,38769,38770,38771,38772,38773,38774,38775,38776,38777,38778,38779,38780,38781,38782,38783,38784,38785,38786,38787,38788,38789,38790,38791,38792,38793,38794,38795,38796,38797,38798,38799,38800,38801,38802,38803,38804,38805,38806,38807,38808,38809,38810,38811,38812,38813,38814,38815,38816,38817,38818,38819,38820,38821,38822,38823,38824,38825,38826,38827,38828,38829,38830,38831,38832,38833,38834,38835,38836,38837,38838,38839,38840,38841,38842,38843,38844,38845,38846,38847,38848,38849,38850,38851,38852,38853,38854,38855,38857,38858,38859,38860,38861,38862,38863,38864,38865,38866,38867,38868,38869,38870,38871,38872,38873,38874,38875,38876,38877,38878,38879,38880,38881,38882,38883,38884,38885,38886,38887,38888,38889,38890,38891,38892,38893,38894,38895,38896,38897,38898,38899,38900,38901,38902,38903,38904,38905,38906,38907,38908,38909,38910,38911,38912,38913,38914,38915,38916,38917,38918,38919,38920,38921,38922,38923,38924,38925,38926,38927,38928,38929,38930,38931,38932,38933,38934,38935,38936,38937,38938,38939,38940,38941,38942,38943,38944,38945,38946,38947,38948,38949,38950,38951,38952,38953,38954,38955,38956,38957,38958,38959,38960,38961,38962,38963,38964,38965,38966,38967,38968,38969,38970,38971,38972,38973,38974,38975,38976,38977,38978,38979,38980,38981,38982,38983,38984,38985,38986,38987,38988,38989,38990,38991,38992,38993,38994,38995,38996,38997,38998,38999,39000,39001,39002,39003,39004,39005,39006,39007,39008,39009,39010,39011,39012,39013,39014,39015,39016,39017,39018,39019,39020,39021,39022,39023,39024,39025,39026,39027,39028,39029,39030,39031,39032,39033,39034,39035,39036,39037,39038,39039,39040,39041,39042,39043,39044,39045,39046,39047,39048,39049,39050,39051,39052,39053,39054,39055,39056,39057,39058,39059,39060,39061,39062,39063,39065,39066,39067,39068,39069,39070,39071,39072,39073,39074,39075,39076,39077,39078,39079,39080,39081,39082,39083,39084,39085,39086,39087,39088,39089,39090,39091,39092,39093,39094,39095,39096,39097,39098,39099,39100,39101,39102,39103,39104,39105,39106,39107,39108,39109,39110,39111,39112,39113,39114,39115,39116,39117,39118,39119,39120,39121,39122,39123,39124,39125,39126,39127,39128,39129,39130,39131,39132,39133,39134,39135,39136,39137,39138,39139,39140,39141,39142,39143,39144,39145,39146,39147,39148,39149,39150,39151,39152,39153,39154,39155,39156,39157,39158,39159,39160,39161,39162,39163,39164,39166,39167,39168,39169,39170,39171,39172,39173,39174,39175,39176,39177,39178,39179,39180,39181,39182,39183,39184,39185,39186,39187,39188,39189,39190,39191,39192,39193,39194,39195,39196,39197,39198,39199,39200,39201,39202,39203,39204,39205,39206,39207,39208,39209,39210,39211,39212,39213,39214,39215,39216,39217,39218,39219,39220,39221,39222,39223,39224,39225,39226,39227,39228,39229,39230,39231,39232,39233,39234,39235,39236,39237,39238,39239,39240,39241,39242,39243,39244,39245,39246,39247,39248,39249,39250,39251,39252,39253,39254,39255,39256,39257,39258,39259,39260,39261,39262,39263,39264,39265,39266,39267,39268,39269,39270,39271,39272,39273,39274,39275,39276,39277,39278,39279,39280,39281,39282,39283,39284,39285,39286,39287,39288,39289,39290,39291,39292,39293,39294,39295,39296,39297,39298,39299,39300,39301,39302,39303,39304,39305,39306,39307,39308,39309,39311,39312,39313,39314,39315,39316,39317,39318,39319,39320,39321,39322,39323,39324,39325,39326,39327,39328,39329,39330,39331,39333,39334,39335,39336,39338,39339,39340,39341,39342,39343,39344,39345,39346,39347,39348,39349,39350,39351,39352,39353,39354,39355,39356,39357,39358,39359,39360,39361,39362,39363,39364,39365,39366,39367,39369,39370,39371,39372,39373,39374,39375,39376,39377,39378,39379,39380,39381,39382,39383,39384,39385,39386,39387,39388,39389,39390,39391,39392,39393,39394,39395,39396,39397,39398,39399,39400,39401,39402,39403,39404,39405,39406,39407,39408,39409,39410,39411,39412,39413,39414,39415,39416,39417,39418,39419,39420,39421,39422,39423,39424,39425,39426,39427,39428,39429,39430,39431,39432,39433,39434,39435,39436,39437,39438,39439,39440,39441,39442,39443,39444,39445,39446,39447,39448,39449,39450,39451,39452,39453,39454,39455,39456,39457,39458,39459,39460,39461,39462,39463,39464,39465,39466,39467,39468,39469,39470,39471,39472,39473,39474,39475,39476,39477,39478,39479,39480,39481,39482,39483,39484,39485,39486,39487,39488,39489,39490,39491,39492,39493,39494,39495,39496,39497,39498,39499,39500,39501,39502,39503,39504,39505,39506,39507,39508,39509,39510,39511,39512,39513,39514,39515,39516,39517,39518,39519,39520,39521,39522,39523,39524,39525,39526,39527,39528,39529,39530,39531,39532,39533,39534,39535,39536,39537,39538,39539,39540,39541,39542,39543,39544,39545,39546,39547,39548,39549,39550,39551,39552,39553,39554,39555,39556,39557,39558,39559,39560,39561,39562,39563,39564,39565,39566,39567,39568,39569,39570,39571,39572,39573,39574,39575,39576,39577,39578,39579,39580,39581,39583,39584,39585,39586,39587,39588,39589,39590,39591,39592,39593,39594,39595,39596,39597,39598,39599,39600,39601,39602,39603,39604,39605,39606,39607,39608,39609,39610,39612,39613,39614,39615,39616,39617,39618,39619,39620,39621,39625,39627,39628,39629,39630,39631,39632,39633,39634,39635,39636,39637,39638,39639,39640,39641,39642,39643,39645,39647,39648,39649,39650,39651,39652,39653,39654,39655,39656,39657,39658,39659,39660,39661,39662,39663,39664,39665,39666,39667,39668,39669,39670,39671,39672,39673,39674,39676,39677,39678,39679,39680,39681,39682,39683,39684,39685,39686,39687,39688,39689,39690,39691,39692,39693,39694,39695,39696,39697,39698,39699,39700,39701,39702,39703,39704,39705,39706,39707,39708,39709,39710,39711,39712,39713,39714,39715,39716,39717,39718,39719,39720,39721,39722,39723,39724,39725,39727,39728,39729,39730,39731,39732,39733,39734,39735,39736,39737,39738,39739,39740,39741,39742,39743,39744,39746,39747,39748,39749,39750,39751,39752,39753,39754,39755,39756,39757,39758,39759,39760,39761,39762,39763,39764,39765,39766,39767,39768,39769,39770,39771,39772,39773,39774,39775,39776,39777,39778,39779,39780,39781,39782,39784,39785,39786,39787,39788,39789,39790,39791,39792,39793,39794,39795,39796,39797,39798,39799,39800,39801,39802,39803,39804,39805,39806,39807,39808,39809,39810,39811,39813,39814,39815,39816,39817,39818,39819,39820,39821,39822,39823,39824,39825,39826,39827,39828,39829,39830,39831,39832,39833,39834,39835,39836,39837,39838,39839,39840,39842,39843,39844,39845,39846,39847,39848,39849,39850,39851,39852,39853,39854,39855,39856,39857,39858,39859,39860,39861,39862,39863,39864,39865,39866,39867,39868,39869,39871,39872,39873,39874,39875,39876,39877,39878,39879,39880,39881,39882,39883,39884,39885,39886,39887,39888,39889,39890,39891,39892,39893,39894,39895,39896,39898,39899,39900,39901,39902,39903,39904,39905,39906,39907,39908,39909,39910,39911,39912,39913,39914,39915,39916,39917,39918,39919,39920,39921,39922,39923,39924,39925,39926,39927,39928,39929,39930,39931,39932,39933,39935,39936,39937,39938,39939,39940,39941,39942,39943,39944,39946,39947,39948,39949,39950,39951,39952,39953,39954,39955,39956,39957,39958,39959,39960,39961,39962,39964,39966,39967,39968,39969,39970,39971,39972,39973,39974,39975,39977,39978,39979,39980,39981,39982,39983,39984,39985,39986,39987,39988,39989,39990,39991,39992,39993,39994,39995,39996,39997,39998,39999,40000,40001,40002,40003,40004,40005,40006,40007,40008,40009,40010,40011,40012,40013,40014,40015,40017,40018,40019,40020,40021,40022,40023,40024,40025,40026,40027,40028,40029,40030,40031,40032,40033,40034,40035,40036,40037,40038,40039,40040,40041,40042,40043,40044,40045,40046,40047,40048,40049,40050,40051,40052,40053,40054,40055,40056,40057,40058,40059,40060,40061,40062,40063,40064,40065,40066,40067,40068,40069,40070,40071,40072,40073,40074,40075,40076,40077,40078,40079,40080,40081,40082,40083,40084,40085,40086,40087,40088,40089,40090,40091,40092,40093,40094,40095,40096,40097,40098,40099,40100,40101,40102,40103,40104,40105,40106,40107,40108,40109,40110,40111,40112,40113,40114,40115,40116,40117,40118,40119,40120,40121,40122,40123,40125,40126,40127,40128,40129,40130,40131,40132,40133,40134,40135,40136,40137,40138,40139,40140,40141,40142,40143,40144,40145,40146,40147,40148,40149,40150,40151,40152,40153,40154,40155,40156,40157,40158,40159,40160,40162,40163,40164,40165,40166,40167,40168,40169,40170,40171,40172,40173,40174,40175,40176,40499,40500,40501,40502,40616,40618,40619,40620,40621,40622,40623,40624,40625,40626,40627,40628,40629,40630,40631,40632,40633,40637,40638,40639,40640,40641,40642,40643,40644,40645,40646,40647,40648,40649,40650,40651,40652,40653,40654,40655,40656,40657,40658,40659,40660,40661,40662,40663,40664,40665,40666,40667,40668,40669,40670,40671,40672,40673,40674,40675,40676,40677,40678,40679,40680,40681,40682,40683,40684,40685,40686,40687,40688,40689,40690,40691,40692,40693,40694,40695,40696,40698,40699,40700,40701,40702,40703,40704,40705,40706,40707,40708,40709,40710,40711,40712,40713,40714,40715,40716,40717,40718,40719,40720,40721,40722,40723,40724,40728,40729,40730,40731,40732,40733,40734,40735,40736,40737,40738,40739,40740,40741,40745,40746,40747,40748,40749,40750,40751,40752,40753,40754,40755,40756,40757,40758,40759,40760,40761,40762,40763,40764,40765,40766,40767,40768,40769,40770,40771,40772,40776,40777,40778,40852,40853,40854,40855,40932,40933,40934,41011,41012,41013,41090,41091,41092,41169,41170,41171,41248,41249,41250,41327,41328,41329,41330,41331,41332,41333,41334,41335,41336,41337,41338,41339,41340,41341,41342,41343,41344,41345,41346,41347,41348,41349,41351,41352,41353,41354,41355,41356,41357,41358,41359,41360,41361,41362,41363,41364,41365,41366,41367,41368,41369,41370,41371,41372,41373,41374,41375,41376,41377,41378,41379,41380,41381,41382,41383,41384,41385,41386,41387,41388,41389,41390,41391,41392,41393,41394,41395,41396,41397,41398,41399,41400,41401,41402,41403,41404,41405,41406,41407,41408,41409,41410,41415,41417,41418,41419,41420,41422,41423,41424,41425,41426,41427,41428,41429,41430,41431,41432,41433,41434,41435,41436,41437,41438,41439,41440,41441,41442,41443,41444,41445,41446,41447,41448,41449,41450,41451,41452,41453,41454,41455,41456,41457,41458,41459,41460,41461,41462,41463,41464,41465,41466,41467,41468,41469,41470,41471,41472,41473,41474,41475,41477,41478,41479,41480,41486,41487,41488,41489,41490,41491,41492,41493,41494,41495,41496,41497,41498,41499,41500,41501,41502,41503,41504,41505,41506,41507,41508,41509,41510,41511,41512,41513,41514,41515,41516,41517,41518,41519,41520,41521,41522,41523,41524,41525,41526,41527) 
                and vacs_ahst.inp_st = '1'  
                    ORDER BY date DESC  LIMIT 0, 10
```

[image]

why main table is sale when FROM vacs_ahst

is make Using temporary; Using filesort and query too slow